# Access values from constructor, from passing data to stateless widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

here is my code,

```
class ProfileOthers extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfileOthers({super.key, required this.data});

  final Map<String, dynamic> data; //I am hoping to make use of this data

  @override
  State<ProfileOthers> createState() => _ProfileOthersState();
}
```

Want to pass arguments in stateless widget from another screen, I'm new in flutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class UserProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
   final Map<String, dynamic> userData;
   const UserProfileScreen ({super.key, required this.userData});

  @override
  State<UserProfileScreen> createState() => _UserProfileScreenState();
}
```

you can access this parameter as shown below,

```
Text(widget.userData['name']),
```

Answer (score 0):

one simple way to access variables passed through initializing that widget within the build method would be using

```
    widget.data
```

where you want like displaying it within a string.

Using the code you provided you could write something like this:

```
class ProfileOthers extends StatefulWidget {
    const ProfileOthers({super.key, required this.data});

    final Map<String, dynamic> data; 

    @override
    State<ProfileOthers> createState() => _ProfileOthersState();
}

class _ProfileOthersState extends State<ProfileOthers> {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
       return Scaffold(
           body: Container(
              child: Text(
                 '${widget.data['Sample key value']}'
              ),
           ),
       );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Text(widget.data['key value']),
```

use this parameter